# How do i deploy Laravel 5.7 and Angular 7 on a Nginx on a server

Tags: angular, laravel, web-deployment

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example;

     location / {

    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

      }

      location /api {

    root /var/www/html/example/public;
    try_files /index.php =404;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

     }
```

above is my server configuration but only angular is working but laravel is not reachable, it keeps showing not found

Comment: Not sure but you are missing the parameters passing to the `index.php`. Usually this looks something like `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the Nginx documentation about [request processing](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) and using the [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias). I came up with the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    # This is the "last resort" nginx will direct to when no other matches with location have been found.
    # It will only look for a file named index.html
    location / {
        root /location/of/angular;
        index index.html;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # All requests that start with /api are directed to the laravel location.
    # It will only look for a file named index.php
    location /api {
        alias /location/of/laravel;
        index index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # All files that end with .php are through fastcgi
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

Sidenote: this has not been tested in a working environment but might help you in the right direction.

Comment: i have tried this it did not work though ,seems like i cant even access the laravel folder

Comment: Can you update your answer with the config you have tried? Maybe we can take another look at it to figure it out.

Comment: @pjoe I have updated my answer. I indeed made an error. Instead of `root /location/of/laravel` you can use `alias /location/of/laravel` to prevent Nginx to get a file in `/location/of/laravel/api/` and point to a different root.

Comment: i have been able solve the issue i used the configuration on Laravel website `location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }`  Thanks for helping