# Deploying a laravel app with a node js app in nginx

Tags: node.js, laravel, nginx

I have a node.js app running using pm2. When I go to my endpoint it works, i see things. But then when I try to do an action that connects to the backend api at laravel, then nothing happens.

This is how I have my nginx config configured:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name make.tube;
    root /maketube/api/public;

    # This is the "last resort" nginx will direct to when no other matches with location have been found.
    # This will proxy pass to another website (should be tested with http://localhost:3000 in your case).
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    # All requests that start with /api are directed to the laravel location.
    # It will only look for a file named index.html
    location /api {
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

When I try to perform an action that should connect to the backend (like sign in) then it fails to work try the signin function on make.tube (http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login/).

Does anyone know how I can get this working so when I perform the sign in it connects to my laravel backend?

Comment: I would recommend using : https://nginxconfig.io/

Comment: Take a look at the answer I posted a day ago on the exact same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54775192/1780996

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen I updated my config with what I thought I needed to do (the bit in location /api.... but still no difference. From what i see, when i do login, it does this call: http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login/ which i feel is wrong, but how could i forward that to the laravel endpoint

Answer (score 0):

By playing around on my local environment I came up with the following simplified version:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.test;
    root /home/vagrant/test;

    # This is the "last resort" nginx will direct to when no other matches with location have been found.
    # This will proxy pass to another website (should be tested with http://localhost:3000 in your case).
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://node.test/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    # All requests that start with /api are directed to the laravel location.
    # It will only look for a file named index.html
    location /api {
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

I managed to `proxy_pass` a request like `http://test.test` to another website `http://node.test`, which displayed the correct content "I am node." Also all request that started with `/api` like `http://test.test/api` where directed to the file in `/home/vagrant/test/api/index.html` which shown "I am api".

In my answer on [54775192](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54775192/1780996) I indeed made an error in the location block. The following:

```
location /api {
    root /location/of/laravel;
    index index.php;
}
```

Will result in an error that nginx tries to get a file named `/location/of/laravel/api`, which does not exist, instead of the intended `/location/of/laravel/api/index.php`.

<strike>Not sure why at this moment.</strike>

This is just how Nginx works. We can make use of [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) to prevent this from happening.

Comment: so updated my question with the new config file after what you mentioned but still doesnt seem to work, anyway to chat somewhere else with you about it? My server skills are lacking quite a bit, basically my first time trying to set something like this up.

Comment: Okay new idea. Would it be a good idea to separate the two configs? Lets say you make a correct nginx vhost config for Laravel with `server_name api.make.tube` and one for the pm2 with `server_name make.tube` following [this](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/pm2-nginx-production-setup) guide.